# Passing in an instance variable as an argument in a class method?

Tags: python

I'm trying to refactor a very repetitive section of code.

I have a class that has two instance variables that get updated:

```
class Alerter(object):

    'Sends email regarding information about unmapped positions and trades'

    def __init__(self, job):
        self.job = job
        self.unmappedPositions = None
        self.unmappedTrades = None
```

After my code going through some methods, it creates a table and updates `self.unmappedPositions` and `self.unmappedTrades`:

```
def load_positions(self, filename):
    unmapped_positions_table = etl.fromcsv(filename)
    if 'positions' in filename:
        return self.add_to_unmapped_positions(unmapped_positions_table)
    else:
        return self.add_to_unmapped_trades(unmapped_positions_table)
```

So I have two functions that essentially do the same thing:

```
def add_to_unmapped_trades(self, table):
    if self.unmappedTrades:
        Logger.info("Adding to unmapped")
        self.unmappedTrades = self.unmappedTrades.cat(
            table).cache()
    else:
        Logger.info("Making new unmapped")
        self.unmappedTrades = table
    Logger.info("Data added to unmapped")
    return self.unmappedTrades
```

And:

```
def add_to_unmapped_positions(self, table):
    if self.unmappedPositions:
        Logger.info("Adding to unmapped")
        self.unmappedPositions = self.unmappedPositions.cat(
            table).cache()
    else:
        Logger.info("Making new unmapped")
        self.unmappedPositions = table
    Logger.info("Data added to unmapped")
    return self.unmappedPositions
```

I tried making it one method so that it just passes in a third argument and then figures out what to update. The third argument being the intialized variable, either `self.unmappedPositions` or `self.unmappedTrades`. However, that doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't pass a "variable", `self.unmappedPositions` will evaluate to the current *value* of that attribute. Maybe pass the *name*, `'unmappedPositions'`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've had the key insight that you can write this function independent of any particular storage:

```
def add_to_unmapped(unmapped, table):
    if unmapped:
        Logger.info("Adding to unmapped")
        unmapped = unmapped.cat(table).cache()
    else:
        Logger.info("Making new unmapped")
        unmapped = table
    Logger.info("Data added to unmapped")
    return unmapped
```

This is actually good practice on its own.  For instance, you can write unit tests for it, or if you have two tables (as you do) you can just write the implementation for it once.

If you consider what, abstractly, your two `add_to_unmapped_*` functions do, they:

1. Compute the new table;
2. Save the new table in the object; and
3. Return the new table.

We've now separated out step 1, and you can refactor the wrappers:

```
class Alerter:
    def add_to_unmapped_trades(self, table):
        self.unmappedTrades = add_to_unmapped(self.unmappedTrades, table)
        return self.unmappedTrades
```

Comment: P.S.: there are alternate approaches, either using `setattr` and `getattr`, or using something like a dictionary where you can reference one table or the other by name; but this answer is how I'd do it for real.